# How to efficiently split a large video into multiple parts using Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have large video files (~1.5 GB) and a list of time intervals in seconds, represented as [(1.3, 2.6), ..., (433.1, 455.2)].

The objective is to split the video into segments based on the specified time intervals. Currently, I am using the `ffmpeg-python` library for this task, as shown below:

```
import ffmpeg

parts = [(1.3, 2.6), ..., (433.1, 455.2)]

for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    file_name = f"video{index}.mp4"
    start_time, end_time = part
    
    input_file = ffmpeg.input(movie_path, ss=start_time, to=end_time)
    input_file.output(file_name).run()
```

That works, but it is relatively slow, processing only 1-2 segments per second.

What is a more efficient way or library that can potentially load the entire video into memory and perform the cutting operation with multiple outputs or something like that?

Comment: Do any of the intervals overlap?